# Logic levels on tri-state buffer,

Tags: spi, logic-level, tri-state

i am working on some CPLD-controlled SPI devices that will be daisy-chained together. I will be using 74VHCT126AFTTR tri-state buffers to disconnect the SPI and Slave Select lines on the device from the daisy-chaining cable.

I have now a few questions:

The 74VHCT126AFTTR buffer will be powered by a 5V power supply line that is shared with the devices. With this voltage supply, will this buffer a 3.3V logic level SPI signal to a 3.3V logic level on the buffer's output?

When the VCC line on the buffer is set to ground will this affect the input lines of the buffer significantly? Could this make a problem for the SPI communication of other devices on the same BUS?

Comment: A diagram showing where you're using the HCT126 in your system (what is driving it and what is it driving) would help make your question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The 74VHCT126AFTTR buffer will be powered by a 5V power supply line that is shared with the devices. With this voltage supply, will this buffer a 3.3V logic level SPI signal to a 3.3V logic level on the buffer's output?

The HCT family has CMOS outputs but TTL-compatible inputs.

That means it has a lower voltage input threshold. Any input above ~1 V will be interpreted as high, which means you can drive it with 3 V logic, even if it's powered by 5 V.

But its output is a 5 V CMOS signal, with (per the Panasonic datasheet) a minimum voltage of 4.5 V when high. So if you are using this to drive a load powered by 3.3 V, you'll need to be sure the load's inputs are 5-V tolerant.

> When the VCC line on the buffer is set to ground will this affect the input lines of the buffer significantly?

According to the datasheet,

> > Input protection and output circuit ensure that 0 to 5.5 V can be applied to the input and output (Note) pins without regard to the supply voltage...Note: Output in off-state

so you should be okay, provided you hold the `G` pin low on the '126.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would a sn74ls126 buffer then provide 3.3V  logic level on its output? My device is not suitable for 5V logic.

Comment: @Christoph, The LS126 has a 5 V TTL output. But that might not damage some 3.3-V-powered loads. You'd need to look at the datasheets of all the parts involved to be sure. Also, I doubt the LS126 will have the same ability to not load the bus when not powered on as the HCT126.